# asp:GridView not getting info from SqlDataAdapter with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have been trying to get an SqlAdapter to get info from a SqlCommand that uses a stored Procedure to get info from the SQL server. I know that the SQL stored Procedure works and that the SqlCommand works (since I tested them out separate without SqlAdapter). Here is the code:

```
    try
    {
         SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         SqlCommandBuilder command = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
         DataTable table = new DataTable();
         table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
         dataAdapter.Fill(table);
         grid.DataSource = table;
    }catch(Exception er){}
```

This piece of code does not run into any exception and the SqlCommand seems to connect to the Sql Server just fine. I did assign the correct parameters and set the correct Stored Procedure into the SqlCommand also. The DataTable "table" does have 5 columns in it (which is the same amount in the SQL table). Here is the asp code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server">
        <columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="data_1" HeaderText="data_1" sortExpression="data_1">
            <asp:BoundField DataField="data_2" HeaderText="data_2" sortExpression="data_2">
            <asp:BoundField DataField="data_3" HeaderText="data_3" sortExpression="data_3">
            <asp:BoundField DataField="data_4" HeaderText="data_4" sortExpression="data_4">
            <asp:BoundField DataField="data_5" HeaderText="data_5" sortExpression="data_5">
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call grid.DataBind() at the end.